# Why can't selenium find this web element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to get selenium in python to find the "Allow all" button for the cookies pop up on this website:

https://www.dice.com/jobs

and it can't find the login button either

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.dice.com/jobs")
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cmpwelcomebtnyes")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "cmpwelcomebtnyes").click()
```

This just comes back with TimeoutException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element you are looking for is in a shadow-root. Selenium needs special instructions to be able to see inside it... similar to an IFRAME, if you are familiar with that. When you inspect the page, it looks like

```
<body>
  <div id="cmpwrapper" class="cmpwrapper">
    #shadow-root (open)
      <div id="cmpbox" ...>
```

We need to grab the element that contains the shadow-root `#cmpwrapper`, grab the shadow_root, and then perform actions from there.

You can find working code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.dice.com/jobs')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cmpwrapper')))
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, 'cmpwelcomebtnyes').click()
```

---

A couple additional notes:

1. As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to use a separate driver manager. Selenium now has a built in [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager). The code above reflects the changes.
2. When you use a `WebDriverWait` that waits for an element, the `.until()` method returns the element so you can assign the return to a variable, etc. and use it so you don't have to scrape the page twice. See the example below

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id")))
   driver.find_element(By.ID, "id").click()
   ```

   can be simplified to

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id"))).click()
   ```

   or for variable assignment,

   ```
   e = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id")))
   e.click()
   ```